# Creating a new file, writing to it and uploading to S3 using Python in Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, upload

I am trying to create a new file using Python in AWS Lambda and write to it and then upload to an S3 bucket.  I want each filename to be unique based on a variable.   In this instance it's submission_id.

```
import json
import sys
import logging
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')
```

## Parse the data from webhook API call (This all works fine)

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
     form_data = json.loads(event['body'])
     form_id = (form_data['FormID'])
     submission_id = (form_data['UniqueID'])
```

## Create new file with results and upload to S3.

## Want to use submission_id as filename variable.

```
     data_file = open('/tmp/submission_id' + '.txt', 'w+')
     data_file.write(str(form_data))
     data_file.close()
```

## Upload the file to S3 bucket

```
     client.upload_file('/tmp/submission_id', 'mb-sentiment' , 'data_file')
```

The error I am receiving is as follows.

[ERROR] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/submission_id'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 24, in lambda_handler
    client.upload_file('/tmp/submission_id', 'mb-sentiment' , 'data_file')

Does anyone have any idea on how I can accurately code this?  This does not seem to be anything difficult, but I am a newbie getting up to speed. Checked some other posts but none seem to address this particular use case.

Thanks!

Comment: data_file = open('/tmp/' + submission_id + '.txt', 'w+')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that you should have `.txt` at the end:

```
client.upload_file('/tmp/submission_id.txt', 'mb-sentiment' , 'data_file')
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Marcin.   So I made that change which got me past that error and got the file to S3.  But the 'data_file' name kept being used for the filename.  So I updated that and it's all working now.                                                                              
Here is the updated working code:       client.upload_file('/tmp/submission_id.txt', 'mb-sentiment', submission_id + '.txt')

Comment: @charlie Glad to hear. So guess its working now? If so, acceptance of answer would be appreciated.